# pandas: searching for partial strings across multiple columns and outputting values for each row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this one:

```
data =  {'fce1_1': ['K701', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'K876', 'Amy'], 
        'fce1_2': ['K712', 'Molly', 'K709', 'Jape', 'Amy'], 
        'fce2_1': ['K703', 'K719', 'Tina', 'I841', 'K987'],
        'fce2_2': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

fce1_1 fce1_2 fce2_1 fce2_2
K701   K712   K703   25
Molly  Molly  K719   94
Tina   K709   Tina   57
...etc
```

I would like to search each row of the df for any values starting with 'K' and return the value of 'K***' that is closest to the column at the right of the dataframe. For example:

```
fce1_1 fce1_2 fce2_1 fce2_2 new_col
K701   K712   K703   25     K703
Molly  Molly  K719   94     K719
Tina   K709   Tina   57     K709
...etc
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean when you say `that is closest to the column at the right`?

Comment: I meant col `fce2_2` will be prioritized over col `fce2_1`..etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) a `lambda` on the df row-wise which checks whether the first character [`startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html#pandas.Series.str.startswith) 'K' and returns the [`last_valid_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.last_valid_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.last_valid_index) which indexes that column on a row basis:

```
In [35]:
df['new_col'] = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x[x[x.str.startswith('K')].last_valid_index()], axis=1)
df

Out[35]:
  fce1_1 fce1_2 fce2_1  fce2_2 new_col
0   K701   K712   K703      25    K703
1  Molly  Molly   K719      94    K719
2   Tina   K709   Tina      57    K709
3   K876   Jape   I841      62    K876
4    Amy    Amy   K987      70    K987
```

Breakdown of the above:

```
In [38]:
df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.startswith('K'), axis=1)
​
Out[38]:
  fce1_1 fce1_2 fce2_1 fce2_2
0   True   True   True  False
1  False  False   True  False
2  False   True  False  False
3   True  False  False  False
4  False  False   True  False

In [39]:    
df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x[x.str.startswith('K')].last_valid_index(), axis=1)

Out[39]:
0    fce2_1
1    fce2_1
2    fce1_2
3    fce1_1
4    fce2_1
dtype: object
```

**EDIT**

To handle no matches row-wise we can have a conditional condition inside the `lambda`:

```
In [67]:
data =  {'fce1_1': [np.NaN, 'Molly', 'Tina', 'K876', 'Amy'], 
        'fce1_2': [np.NaN, 'Molly', 'K709', 'Jape', 'Amy'], 
        'fce2_1': [np.NaN, 'K719', 'Tina', 'I841', 'K987'],
        'fce2_2': np.NaN}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['new_col'] = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x[x.str.startswith('K')].last_valid_index() if x.str.startswith('K').any() else 'No Match', axis=1)
df

Out[67]:
  fce1_1 fce1_2 fce2_1  fce2_2   new_col
0    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN  No Match
1  Molly  Molly   K719     NaN    fce2_1
2   Tina   K709   Tina     NaN    fce1_2
3   K876   Jape   I841     NaN    fce1_1
4    Amy    Amy   K987     NaN    fce2_1
```

Comment: This works great on the test df but in my real data I am sometimes missing a K-value. `.last_valid_index()` appears to throw an error when this is the case. Is there an easy way to insert a `np.NaN` or other string value when there is no 'K***' value? Checked the pandas doc but limited info on the method.

Comment: What do you want instead an empty string or something like 'No Match' as the entry?

Comment: Yes empty string or 'no match' is fine.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks @EdChum !